# Total de Facebook no es real en Google Analytics

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

He notado que  en la analítica de mi sitio web, si entro en la categoría Medios Sociales, y veo el total en Facebook, este número es únicamente el total de todos los "referral" de Facebook, pero no incluye el resto de medios. Así que, por ejemplo, si yo comparto en mi facebook la url: 
http://www.gxxxx.com/productos/ofertas/promociones-futboleras.html?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cl...

Esta última, con utm_medium=clictoweb, no aparece contabilizada en el total de Facebook de la categoría Medios Sociales, ni tampoco en la opción de Facebook, de la categoría Social, de Canales.

¿Será que estoy haciendo alguna mala práctica que esté provocando que mi resultado no incluya este tipo de vínculos?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado te comento que tienes que configurar la sección de filtros con el detalle de fuente y medio para que se consideren los que necesites, estos son los que yo detecto normalmente probablemente te ayude:

apps.facebook.com / referral
beta.facebook.com / referral
business.facebook.com / referral
es-es.facebook.com / referral
es-la.facebook.com / referral
facebook / (not set)
facebook / LinkAd
facebook / cpc
facebook / social
facebook-boton / social
facebook-post / social
facebook.com / referral
intern.facebook.com / referral
l.facebook.com / referral
lm.facebook.com / referral
m.facebook.com / referral
mobile.facebook.com / referral
review.intern.facebook.com / referral
web.facebook.com / referral

*igual es a criterio de cada administrador la configuración de cada cuenta.

Saludos,
JG